# iPhone: - why  id's in "in-App Purchase" do not match?

Tags: iphone, ios5, in-app-purchase

I am implementing inapp purchase in my app. I have submitted to app on the app store but the apple id is different for my app and for inapp purchase. Is that the problem for error?

[image]

I want to mention that my app is very large in size so testing inapp purchase I have created one dummy app with same bundle id and provisioning profile and submitted that app on app store. so due to this reason problem occurs?

Comment: have u submitted the dummy app for testing.?

Comment: yup I have submitted dummy app not original app due to its large size.

Comment: can u show the error message encountered in console..

Comment: My error message is as follows:                               Transaction Purchasing====================
An error encounterd
Transaction Failed====================